# How to conditionally run an http request inside combineLatest?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this combineLatest block that runs 2 http requests but I want the second request to only run if a certain condition is met.

```
combineLatest([
  this.leadsService.fetchALLLeadsActivityChart(this.clientId, this.getParams(optionsCurrent)),
  this.leadsService.fetchALLLeadsActivityChart(this.clientId, this.getParams(optionsPrevious))]).pipe(takeUntil(this.chartSubscription)).subscribe(([current, previous]) => {
    if(current.meta.success && previous.meta.success){
      this.processGraphData({current: current.results, previous: previous.results});
    } 
  });
```

Basically I want the second leadsService to only run if

```
this.selectedDateFilter.enableComparisons = true;
```

How do I fit that in the combineLatest block? Or does it need to be a separate call and just store the first requests result in a variable? Thank you for the help.

Comment: why don't you take those http calls in two observables and then you can easily control if you want to call them or not.

Comment: I want to let this.processGraphData() to wait before doing operations on the result from the combinelatest block. could it work if i separate the http calls into two observables?

Comment: yes. no http request happens until you subscribe the observables
Can't write code here, so I am writing it in a comment

Comment: I see. thank you. Will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take those calls on seperate observables and then subscribe to them with combineLatest.

```
$o1 = this.leadsService.fetchALLLeadsActivityChart(this.clientId, this.getParams(optionsCurrent));
if(this.selectedDateFilter.enableComparisons == true) {
    $o2 = this.leadsService.fetchALLLeadsActivityChart(this.clientId, 
    this.getParams(optionsPrevious));
}
combineLatest($o1, $o2).subscribe([current, previous]) => {
    if(current.meta.success && previous.meta.success){
        this.processGraphData({current: current.results, previous: previous.results});
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
combineLatest([
  this.leadsService.fetchALLLeadsActivityChart(this.clientId, this.getParams(optionsCurrent)), 
  this.leadsService.fetchALLLeadsActivityChart(this.clientId, this.getParams(optionsPrevious)),
])
.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.chartSubscription),
  filter(([current, previous]) => current.meta.success && previous.meta.success),
  switchMap(([current, previous]) => this.processGraphData({current: current.results, previous: previous.results}))
)
.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```